# New to Google Apps Script's HTML service

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I'm just starting to use Google Apps Script's HTML service to create a UI. Starting out very basic and Google's documentation seems to be very incomplete (let me know if I missed something). I followed this example: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#withUserObject(Object) and got it to work, but I don't understand where the "this" came from (in the HTML code) and how the order of operations works there.

In order to wrap my mind around this, I'm trying to make something where I can put in text, push a button, and it will display the same text in all-caps. Here's what I've got so far:

Google Script:

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index')
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script>
      function capitalize(input){
        return input.toUpperCase();
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    Put some text here: <input type="text" name="words"><br>
    <input name="button" type="button" value="CAPITALIZE" onclick="google.script.run
          .withSuccessHandler(capitalize)
          .withUserObject(words)"><br><br>
    Here is your text:
  </body>
</html>
```

Any help is GREATLY appreciated!

Comment: to make a valid question, include your code in the question (not a ĺink) and show us the issue you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for .gs is actually really good. Don't go into any language's docs expecting "full explanations" for every use case though.

`google.script.run` is only needed when you want to pass data to a server-side .gs function ( as documented at the top of the page you linked to ).

What you're asking for seems to be all client-side manipulation though, with no need to pass data to a .gs function.

try these adjustments:

```
// get value of a text box and set it into html of a <span> element
function capitalize(){
  document.getElementById('userInput').innerHTML = 
  document.getElementById("words").value.toUpperCase();
}

onclick="capitalize()"><br><br>
Here is your text:<span id="userInput"></span>
```

Comment: Made the changes you suggested and it didn't work. Since I can't really post code here, this is where you can see it if you want to verify I did it correctly: https://script.google.com/d/1iOSeSHCaWPIuGuZfL-swcxFcsBMm6M3irqwHJRYGuE9QNNJOLTPKLrh9/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Also, wasn't saying that .gs had bad documentation, but I was saying that .html (for the purposes here of creating a UI for Google Apps Script) has bad documentation.

Comment: `document.getElementById("words")`, does your words input have an id attribute?

Comment: the [UI docs for Add-ons](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/style) are good.

Comment: Ah, no it didn't have an id. I haven't done much with html so I forgot. Thanks!